# Real length of Salesforce formula-filed

Tags: salesforce, formula, force.com, sfdc

I faced with issue that sometimes when I created custom formula-fields on Salesforce objects I couldn't save it, the reason of it was limitation in 5000 characters for such type of field.

The main trouble is that when I copied content of formula to any notepad which can calculate number of characters I saw, that there was less than 5000 characters. After some investigations I found that mentions of other formula-fields and also some methods, like `TODAY()`, can implicitly increase number of characters. In this way the real length will be more than number of character that you type.

My question - how can I see the real amount of formula-field characters and how to know which parts of formula adds extra-amount?

Comment: I also asked this question on http://salesforce.stackexchange.com - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143151/real-length-of-salesforce-formula-filed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in a Formula Field can exceed the maximum number of characters allowed in two ways:

1. Directly in the Formula Field's characters (3900). (I think your case)
2. In the overall size of the Formula after other included Formula
   Fields are factored in (5000) bytes.

You can refer this to find workaround [Formula Field exceeds maximum number of characters](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Formula-field-exceeds-maximum-number-of-characters-1327109401516&language=en_US)

Hope this Helps !!

Thanks,
Swayam

Comment: Thanks for your answer!